# How can I split the product quantity based on a group quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with list of products with quantities and their group. I want to divide them equally based on the product group quantity. Each group may contain one or more products.

The following table shows the products and their group wise quantity

```
SortOrder   ProductID   ToolGroup   ToolGroupQty    Quantity
1           PRD1            A1         180          900
2           PRD2            A2         77           125
3           PRD3            A2         77           125
4           PRD4            A2         77           135
5           PRD5            A3         128          125
6           PRD6            A3         128          520
7           PRD7            A4         77           385
```

The code I tried is

```
declare @CombinationGroupTable table(SortOrder int,ProductID nvarchar(50),Combination   nvarchar(20),Tools  int,ToolGroup nvarchar(10),ToolGroupQty int,Market nvarchar(20),Quantity int,isUpdated char(10))

insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(1,'PRD1','A',7,'A1',180,'M0002',900,NULL)
insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(2,'PRD2','A',3,'A2',77,'M0003',125,NULL)
insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(3,'PRD3','A',3,'A2',77,'M0004',125,NULL)
insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(4,'PRD4','A',3,'A2',77,'M0004',135,NULL)
insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(5,'PRD5','A',5,'A3',128,'M0001',125,NULL)
insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(6,'PRD6','A',5,'A3',128,'M0003',520,NULL)
insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(7,'PRD7','A',3,'A4',77,'M0004',385, NULL)

select * from @CombinationGroupTable
declare @SortOrder int,@productID nvarchar(100),@Quantity int,@shift char(1),@prevQty int,@productCode nvarchar(100)
declare @Combination nvarchar(20),@Market nvarchar(50),@Tools int, @prevTools int,@prevComb nvarchar(10), @ToolGroupName nvarchar(20),@tGroupCount int
declare @MaxgroupID nvarchar(20),@NextGroup nvarchar(20), @MaxComb int,@LastSortOrder int,@toCompensate int,@ToolGroup nvarchar(20), @ToolGroupQty int
declare @minOrder int , @maxOrder int, @combProdID nvarchar(100), @combMarket nvarchar(20), @combQty int, @shiftFact int,@combTools int,@combToolsGroup nvarchar(10), @ToolQty int, @toolshiftQty int,@combOrder int, @CToolGroup nvarchar(20)
declare @shiftQty int = 464,@ToolsCount int = 18
declare  @ProdQty table(ID int identity(1,1),SortOrder int,ProductID nvarchar(100),Quantity int,Market nvarchar(10),GroupNo int,ToolGroup nvarchar(20))
declare @RID int,@SOrder int,@CCombination nvarchar(20), @CTotal int, @CompensationQty int,@LastQty int,@RemaininQty int,@PreviousQty int,@ctoolgroupQty int, @tgCompensate int
declare @toolGroupTable table(ToolGroup nvarchar(10),GroupQuantity int,ActQuantity int)

                declare planSchedule cursor for select SortOrder,ProductID,Combination,Tools,ToolGroup,ToolGroupQty,Market,Quantity from @CombinationGroupTable order by SortOrder
                open planSchedule
                fetch next from planSchedule into @sortOrder,@ProductID,@Combination,@Tools,@ToolGroup,@ToolGroupQty,@Market,@Quantity
                while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
                begin

                select  top 1 @MaxComb = isnull(GroupNo,1) from @ProdQty group by GroupNo Order by CAST(GroupNo as int) desc
                set @NextGroup= case when isnull(@LastQty,0) < @shiftQty then isnull(@MaxComb,1) else @MaxComb+1 end

                select @minOrder= MIN(SortOrder),@maxOrder = MAX(SortOrder) from @CombinationGroupTable

                    while @minOrder <= @maxOrder
                    begin

                        select @combMarket= Market,@combQty = Quantity,@combProdID = ProductID,@combTools= Tools,@combToolsGroup= toolGroup,@ctoolgroupQty= ToolGroupQty from @CombinationGroupTable where Combination = @Combination and SortOrder= @minOrder and tools is not null

                        select @ToolQty = cast((3600/62)*(cast(@combTools as numeric)/cast(@ToolsCount as numeric))*8 as int)

                        if(isnull(@Tools,'') <> '' and isnull(@combTools,'') <> '')
                        begin

                                if(isnull(@combQty,0) > @ToolQty)
                                    begin

                                        if((select isnull(sum(quantity),0) from @ProdQty where ToolGroup = @combToolsGroup and GroupNo = @NextGroup) < @ctoolgroupQty)
                                        begin                                                                                           

                                                insert into @ProdQty values(@minOrder,@combProdID,@ctoolgroupQty,@combMarket,@NextGroup,@combToolsGroup)
                                                insert into @toolGroupTable values(@combToolsGroup,@ctoolgroupQty,@ctoolgroupQty)

                                                update @CombinationGroupTable set Quantity= Quantity - @ctoolgroupQty,ToolGroupQty= @ctoolgroupQty,isUpdated='Y' where productID= @combProdID --and ToolGroup = @combToolsGroup                                             
                                        end

                                    end 

                                    else
                                    begin

                                        insert into @ProdQty values(@minOrder,@combProdID,@combQty,@combMarket,@NextGroup,@combToolsGroup)  

                                        insert into @toolGroupTable values(@combToolsGroup,@combQty,@ctoolgroupQty)                                                                     

                                        update @CombinationGroupTable set  Tools = @Tools,Quantity=Quantity-@combQty  where  ProductID = @combProdID --ToolGroup= @ToolGroup and isnull(isUpdated,'N')='N' and SortOrder= @minOrder + 1 and ToolGroup= @combToolsGroup                                  

                                        set @combQty = 0 
                                    end


                        if not exists(select * from @CombinationGroupTable where ProductID = @combProdID and isupdated='Y')
                        update @CombinationGroupTable set Quantity = case when @combQty >= @ToolQty then (Quantity-@ToolQty) else (Quantity-@combQty) end,isUpdated='Y'  where ProductID = @combProdID

                        delete from @CombinationGroupTable where Quantity <= 0


                        end


                        if exists(select * from (select sum(GroupQuantity) Qty,sum(ActQuantity) ActQuantity,ToolGroup from @toolGroupTable group by ToolGroup)A where Qty < ActQuantity)
                        begin
                            set @tgCompensate = 0 

                            select @tgCompensate=ActQuantity-Qty from (
                            select sum(GroupQuantity) Qty,sum(ActQuantity) ActQuantity,ToolGroup from @toolGroupTable group by ToolGroup)A
                            where Qty < ActQuantity

                            select @combMarket= Market,@combQty = Quantity,@combProdID = ProductID,@combTools= Tools,@combToolsGroup= toolGroup,@ctoolgroupQty= ToolGroupQty from @CombinationGroupTable where SortOrder= @minOrder+1  and ToolGroup= @combToolsGroup

                            insert into @ProdQty values(@minOrder,@combProdID,@tgCompensate,@combMarket,@NextGroup,@combToolsGroup)
                            insert into @toolGroupTable values(@combToolsGroup,@tgCompensate,@ctoolgroupQty)

                            update @CombinationGroupTable set Quantity= Quantity - @tgCompensate,Tools=@Tools ,ToolGroupQty= @ToolQty where productID= @combProdID and ToolGroup = @combToolsGroup                          

                            delete from @CombinationGroupTable where Quantity <=0

                            set @tgCompensate = 0 

                            delete from @toolGroupTable



                        end


                        delete from @toolGroupTable
                        delete from @CombinationGroupTable where Quantity <= 0                  

                        set @minOrder= @minOrder+1
                        set @combMarket= '' set @combQty = 0 set @combProdID = '' set @combTools = 0


                    end

                    set @LastQty = 500000

                    delete from @CombinationGroupTable where Quantity <=0

                fetch next from planSchedule into @sortOrder,@ProductID,@Combination,@Tools,@ToolGroup,@ToolGroupQty,@Market,@Quantity
                end

                close planSchedule
                deallocate planSchedule


                select * from @ProdQty
```

The actual result should be as follows

```
SortOrder   ProductID   ToolGroup   Quantity    SplitedGroup
1           PRD1           A1       180          1
2           PRD2           A2       77           1
5           PRD5           A3       125          1
6           PRD6           A3       3            1
7           PRD7           A4       77           1
1           PRD1           A1       180          2
2           PRD2           A2       48           2
3           PRD3           A2       29           2
6           PRD6           A3       129          2
7           PRD7           A4       77           2
1           PRD1           A1       180          3
3           PRD3           A2       77           3
6           PRD6           A3       129          3
7           PRD7           A4       77           3
1           PRD1           A1       180          4
3           PRD3           A2       19           4
4           PRD4           A2       58           4
6           PRD6           A3       129          4
7           PRD7           A4       77           4
1           PRD1           A1       180          5
4           PRD4           A2       77           5
6           PRD6           A3       129          5
7           PRD7           A4       77           5
```

Expected result in excel format
[image]

Comment: please explain the logic required

Comment: The sum of each splitted group should be equal. For this case 463. Each ToolGroup's SUM should be equal to the respective toolgroup quantity.

The sum of each product should be equal to the given quantity in the above table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each product is going to be split in one of three ways. It'll either fill in the end of a bucket already partially filled (though maybe not completely), fill a bucket entirely, or partially fill a new, empty bucket. The idea here is to determine where those boundaries fall (steps 1 and 2) and then generate the output you need based on those parameters (via the three-part union.)

```
with step1 as (
    select *,
        (
          sum(Quantity)
              over (partition by ToolGroup order by SortOrder)
              - Quantity
        ) / ToolGroupQty + 1 as FirstSplitGroup,
        (
          sum(Quantity)
              over (partition by ToolGroup order by SortOrder)
              - Quantity
        ) % ToolGroupQty as GMod
    from data
), step2 as (
    select *,
        FirstSplitGroup as PartialSplitGroup1,
        case when PartialSplitQty1 > 0 then 1 else 0 end as Adj,
        (Quantity - PartialSplitQty1) / ToolGroupQty as FullSplitCnt,
        case when Quantity > ToolGroupQty - GMod
            then (Quantity + GMod) % ToolGroupQty
            else 0
         end as PartialSplitQty2        
    from step1 cross apply (select 
            case when Quantity < ToolGroupQty - GMod
                then Quantity
                else (ToolGroupQty - GMod) % ToolGroupQty
            end PartialSplitQty1
        ) as psq1
), num as (
    select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all
    select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
    select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all
    select 9
)
select 1, 
    ToolGroup,
    PartialSplitGroup1 as SplitGroup,
    ProductId,
    PartialSplitQty1 as SplitQty
from step2
where PartialSplitQty1 > 0
union all
select 2,
    ToolGroup,
    PartialSplitGroup1 + Adj + FullSplitCnt,
    ProductId,
    PartialSplitQty2
from step2
where PartialSplitQty2 > 0
union all
select 3,
    ToolGroup,
    FirstSplitGroup + Adj + n,
    ProductId,
    ToolGroupQty
from step2 inner join num
    on n < FullSplitCnt
order by ToolGroup, SplitGroup, ProductId, SplitQty;
```

https://rextester.com/BBJ90851

Comment: If I change the tool group quantity, for each group , some values are missing

Comment: ToolGroup ToolGroupQty
A1 233
A2 100
A3 166
A4 100

Comment: Problem with PRD3 and PRD4. If I change the tool group quantity to 100

Comment: Are you making sure to change every ToolGroupQty in the group? I assumed they would always all be the same.

Comment: @Vinoth How would it work if ToolGroupQty wasn't the same for every product in a ToolGroup?

Comment: Tool Group Quantity is same for all products in a Tool Group

Comment: For Products PRD2, PRD3 and PRD4 Tool group quantity is 100 which belongs to Tool Group A2. When it was 77 your query works fine. If I change to 100 , It doesn't work.

Comment: The issue arises when a tool group has more than 3 products when I change the Tool group quantity to 100 or above

Comment: @Vinoth I believe the problem is fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its ok now. The problem is solved. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below script. I have consider at most 10 SplitedGroup and created an inline table "B" where I UNION 1 to 10. But you can increase that range if there possibilities of having more SplitedGroup.

You can check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f469c624c2f669d2273827ce7a64c2f6)

```
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SortOrder ORDER BY SortOrder ASC,ToolGroupQty DESC ) RN
FROM
(
    SELECT SortOrder, ProductID,ToolGroup,ToolGroupQty
    FROM
    (
        SELECT SortOrder, ProductID,ToolGroup,ToolGroupQty,
        Quantity/ToolGroupQty N
        FROM your_table
    )A
    INNER JOIN (
        --Here you can add more values to increase the Range
        SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT 2 N UNION ALL SELECT 3 N UNION ALL SELECT 4 N UNION ALL SELECT 5 N UNION ALL
        SELECT 6 N UNION ALL SELECT 7 N UNION ALL SELECT 8 N UNION ALL SELECT 9 N UNION ALL SELECT 10 N
    ) B ON A.N >= B.N

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SortOrder, ProductID,ToolGroup,
    Quantity%ToolGroupQty ToolGroupQty 
    FROM your_table
    WHERE Quantity%ToolGroupQty > 0
)C
```

> Note: I guess you have wrong distribution for SortOrder = 3 in the sample output. As a result you have 23 but my query getting 22 rows in the output.

Comment: mkRabbani Thanks a lot. But the query does not return the required result.

Comment: The sum of each splitted group should be equal. For this case 463. Each ToolGroup's SUM should be equal to the respective toolgroup quantity.

The sum of each product should be equal to the given quantity in the above table.

Comment: The output of my query is same as your first provided sample output. For Prod4 you placed distributed value under 4 and 5. For Prod6 you placed under 1. What is the logic?

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable way I can think to approach this question is to break out the products into quantities of 1 and then recombine them.  It might be possible to do the following approach with larger chunks, but thinking in terms of individual products helps me.

So, you can use a recursive CTE to break out the products.  Then you need to combine them.

That is pretty easy at first glance.  Just enumerate them and divide them into buckets -- this is a simple calculation with window functions.

The following takes a slightly more sophisticated approach:

```
with cte as (
      select sortOrder, productid, toolgroup, 1 as qty, (quantity - 1) as qty_left, toolgroupqty, quantity as orig_quantity, 1 as lev
      from data
      union all
      select sortOrder, productid, toolgroup,
             1 as qty,
             (qty_left - 1) as qty_left,
             toolgroupqty, orig_quantity, lev + 1
      from cte
      where qty_left > 0  and lev < 1000
     ),
     cte2 as (
      select cte.*,
             (row_number() over (order by orig_quantity / toolgroupqty, sortorder, newid()) - 1) * 5 / count(*) over () as bucket
      from cte
     )
select sortorder, productid, toolgroup, count(*) as qty, bucket
from cte2
group by sortorder, productid, toolgroup, bucket
order by bucket, sortorder
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b486b0556a3cb011ef400ee28fb45f8c) is a db<>fiddle.

There appear to be other constraints:

- The amount in a "split" (or bucket) is never more than the `toolquantity`.
- However, there are leftovers so smaller amounts can be handled.

The `partition by` in `cte2` chunks the values based on the quantity divided by the tool quantity.  This helps to guarantee that only one chunk is in each bucket.  Of course, there is no perfect guarantee, because one product might dominate the inputs.

The "5", by the way, is the number of buckets.  It isn't clear from the question how you determine this.

By the way, if this does work for you but you want improvement in performance, I would appreciate if you asked a *new* question.

Comment: The amount in a "split" (or bucket) is never more than the toolquantity.

Comment: If there are any left over will be handled finally

Comment: @Vinoth . . . So is the number of splits based on some calculation on the `toolquantity`?  Can you provide the calculation, perhaps in your question.

Comment: Tool Quantity=(3600/62)*(Tools/18)*8

Comment: For Tool Group A1 = Tool Quantity =(3600*62)*(7/18)*8 => 180